# Cannot use JFrame method from mouselistener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener

I am currently trying developing simple game, but having some trouble with making game menu.  I use JPanel for each states in game menu such as instruction or option and have method in parent JFrame to shuffle them according to what item user click on the menu.

My code is like this (without some simple method like setSize() or setVisible() ).

```
public class Game extends JFrame{

    private JPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
    private JPanel helpPanel; = new HelpPanel();
    private JPanel optionPanel = new OptionPanel();
    private JPanel currentPanel = new JPanel();

    public Game(){
          add(currentPanel);
    }

    public void changePanel(int destination){

          remove(currentPanel);

          if(destination==MAIN_PANEL)
                currentPanel = mainPanel;
          else if(destination==HELP_PANEL)
                currentPanel = helpPanel;
          else if(destination==OPTION_PANEL)
                currentPanel = optionPanel;

          add(currentPanel);
}
```

Everything work perfectly except when I try to use changePanel method in mouselistener, it wasn't responded anything.  Then I try some simple method like this.

```
....
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          removeAll();
          JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Pop when click anywhere.");
}
....
```

I expected my JFrame would be cleared and the dialog poped.  The dialog does pop but for JFrame.   My question is how can I use those simple method from mouselistener.

Sorry for my terrible English.  I am now learning both Java and English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a MouseListener.

I can't tell exactly what you are doing but you should probably be using either a JMenuBar with menus or JButtons. In any case I suggest you start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) to learn the basics of Swing. There are sections on:

1. How to Use Menus
2. How to Use Buttons

to get your started.

Also you should check out the section on `Using a Card Layout`. This is generally the better approach when you want to remove/add panels from a frame.